# Is there any way to back up saved passwords and installed extensions in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, google-chrome-extensions

I registered to many websites and used the "save my password" option offered by Chrome. Is there any way to back up them? Is there anyway to back up the installed extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [synching your browser](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139) (Chrome) with your Google account. I think this way you can have the backup of all the bookmarks and other stuff that is associated with your browser.

Comment: … but where would the backup be stored?

Comment: @slhck I believe the data is stored in your google docs account. I tried this for a bit, but gave up and went back to XMarks (cross browser with Firefox). It left a folder in google docs that I eventually deleted.

Comment: This is they right answer. If you're worried about the visibility of your information; you can choose to encrypt your files with a pass phrase for storage.